# How to make smart installer for ovi applications

Tags: qt, deployment, qt4, symbian, nokia

How to make smart installer for Ovi applications?

Answer (score 2):

Read the [documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/smart-installer-1.0/smartinstaller-wrapper-signing.html). If you build your application with Nokia Qt SDK, qmake will automatically include the Smart Installer. But for Ovi Store, self-signed applications are not accepted. Thus you will need to get a signing certificate from [Symbian Signed](https://www.symbiansigned.com/app/page). This will probably change in the future, I'm not sure what the current status is.