# how to make sis file qt independent

Tags: qt, components, nokia

when I make a program with qt and try to install that .sis file to my cell phone, my phone says qt component is missing, and qt mobility is missing. Ok when I install those to my phone I can run the setup file . However, I want my program to run in any cell phone not only in mine. I mean when I send the .sis file to a friend I don't want him to deal with qt staff and just install the program. I don't know whether I made myself clear , let me summarize I don't want setup .sis file to say qt is missing. Is it possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You should embedded the Nokia Smart Installer to your sis file: http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Nokia_Smart_Installer_for_Symbian. It will automatically install missing Qt components before installing your app.

Also take a look at [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742052/how-to-make-smart-installer-for-ovi-applications)

Comment: When i try to install that, it gives me an error that says: "Not a standalone package"